# The package colors on Draw Something doesn't work

Tags: draw-something

So I played Draw Something (Free version) and had enough coins to buy a color package. When I click on the package, it tells me that I don't have enough coins but then, they take my coins and I don't see my package anywhere.

Comment: Hi, Emily, and welcome to Gaming.SE! Unfortunately, I don't think we'll be able to help you with this particular issue. I could be 100% wrong in saying that, but just in case, might I recommend: https://getsatisfaction.com/drawsomething

Comment: Sorry Emily, but you are doing it right.. get 249 coins, then when drawing something click the plus sign by the colors and select a new set of colors.. That should be all you have to do to unlock them so this looks more like a bug.