# Having problems buying colours

Tags: draw-something

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The package colors on Draw Something doesn't work](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58319/the-package-colors-on-draw-something-doesnt-work)
>   [Lost my colour palette in Draw Something](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59558/lost-my-colour-palette-in-draw-something)

I have more than 900 points collected, but whenever I try to buy more colours, my points are deducted but the colours are not bought. It always says there are not enough coins available.

What do I do?

Comment: @Jupotter I disagree

Comment: Hi Rmi, and welcome to Gaming.SE! Unfortunately, I don't think we'll be able to help you with this particular issue. I could be 100% wrong in saying that, but just in case, might I recommend: getsatisfaction.com/drawsomething

Comment: @Paralytic I believe http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58319/the-package-colors-on-draw-something-doesnt-work should be the correct duplicate

Comment: @YiJiang that definately is a duplicate